# Left shift and Right shift (Like in C) In TI Basic

Tags: ti-basic

How do you use right and left shift in ti basic?
A mathematical way to write left and right shift will also work. I am trying to port some C code to TI basic but I don't know how to left and right shift in ti.

I tried to use a/(2^b) and a*2^b, but it didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?